# How to integrate Bootstrap CSS in an Angular application

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I have two similar very small example Angular applications that integrate Bootstrap CSS. One works and one that I created myself doesn't. It is unclear what the difference is and why it doesn't work in my case.

My steps are as follows:

```
npm install bootstrap --save
```

This updates `package.json` and then subsequently I update `index.html` and add

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Exactly the same line as the working application but in example app that I created using `ng new new-app` it is not working.

Network tab in chrome shows 404. Basically the URL http://localhost:4200/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css cannot be found.

What is the correct / complete way to integratie Bootstrap CSS in an Angular app?

Comment: asnwer by @brk will do the trick if not you can always use a CDN in index.html that will work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are using angular & angular cli

If this is the case then you can actually add the bootstrap.css file in `.angular-cli.json` inside array corresponding to `style` key like this

```
"styles": [
        "styles.less",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      ]
```

Two other possibilities are importing this `bootstrap.css` at main .css file using `@import` or you can require this in the main `index.js` file.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Angular-CLI:

update your .angular-cli.json file to include the bootstrap style:

```
"styles": [
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
],
```

No need to include it in your index.html